# Why did Cain build a city?

Tags: parashat-bereishit

The Torah says (Bereishes 4:17) ‘Cain knew his wife. She conceived and gave birth to Chanoch. Cain was building a city, and he named the city Chanoch, after his son.’ 
So the obvious question is, if there were currently only 6 people alive (Adam, Chava, Sheth, Cain, Mrs Cain, & baby Chanoch) why bother building an entire city? It seems like a couple of tents would’ve been fine.

Comment: Thanks, since this is a duplicate should I delete it?